# define an input suggestion with vba in excel

Tags: excel, vba

im not really sure how to word this but im going to try to describe the issue.

I am building a simple excel spreadsheet to keep track of my spending. each cost i input needs to be classified into a category. I have about 20 different categories and forget what they are.

Rather than scrolling up I would like to script a continuous suggestion prompt when i select a cell in a specific column of the spreadsheet. I want to just be able to read off the suggestion as to which category to input (manually).

See nothing too complex, i just know very little about vba syntax and how to phrase the issue. I think i need like a continuous running sub? again not sure what that is called.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Ken

Comment: Have you considered using a Data Validation drop-down list for your category selections?  This would overcome the problem of forgetting what categories are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could you a simple userform to select and parse data selection into the row you clicked.

First use an Event when you click in the column you want the reminder to pop up in. In this case I choose "D".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim arr
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
      Application.EnableEvents = 0
          UserForm1.Show
          Target = a
      Application.EnableEvents = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Then load the user form with your reminder data and select the reminder data you need from a userform combobox.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim arr
    arr = Array("Unit1", "Unit2", "Unit3", "Unit4", "Unit5", "Unit6", _
                     "Unit7", "Unit8", "Unit9", "Unit10", "Unit11", "Unit12", _
                        "Unit13", "Unit14", "Unit15", "Unit16", "Unit17", "Unit18", _
                          "Unit19", "Unit20")
        Me.ComboBox1.List = arr
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
     a = ComboBox1.Value
     Unload Me
End Sub
```

And you will need to put a public variable in a standard module to store the data you want pasted in your sheet.

```
Public a As String
```

Be sure to change any control names to suit you.